# Can I validate empty data source/blank pdf?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jasper-reports

I'm new in *JasperReports*. So,I have successfully created the report function as I want, I have 3 parameters, which consist of date and 2 strings. So far, it's going very well when the query is having a result (not empty). But if the query is empty, the pdf created will be plain white blank.

So, what I wanna do is, I want to validate it, whenever it's going to generate a plain white pdf, I don't want to show the blank pdf, instead I want to show some error message. Is this possible?

Here is my code, using javascript in JSP.

```
<%
    Connection conn = null;
    try{
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@333.0.0.1:3333:sample", "asd", "asd");
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String method_param = request.getParameter("method");
    if(method_param.equals("default")){
        method_param = "%";
    }

    String date_param = request.getParameter("date");
    if(date_param == ""){
        date_param = "%";
    }

    String status_param = request.getParameter("status");
    if(status_param.equals("default")){
        status_param = "%";
    }


    Map parameters = new HashMap();
    parameters.put("method_param", method_param);
    parameters.put("date_param", date_param);
    parameters.put("status_param", status_param);

    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport("C:/myaddress/lalala/WEB-INF/reports/Reports.jasper", parameters, conn);
    OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"report.pdf\"");
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, outputStream);
    exporter.exportReport(); 

      if (outputStream != null)
        {
          try
          {
            outputStream.close();
          }
          catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
          }
        }


%>
```

It worked well, but I just want to avoid the blank pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a predefined variable called REPORT_COUNT provided by jasper report. It contains the total number of records present in the report.

You can make use of this variable to show a appropriate message such as 'No records found'.

Thanks

Comment: hi, this idea kind of a good one, but when I try it, it still showing me "document has no pages". i think it's because the query resulting in null? but why it can't show the pdf even though it's empty?

Comment: hi,i have already can show the blank pdf with the header and else, when i want to implement using print when expression, why it's not working in the detail part of my report?

Comment: hi, Set the print when expression to new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()==0) and evaluationTime="Report"

Comment: hey, can this be done in the detail part?i have successfully implement what i want in the header part,but when i move it to detail,it leave as blank. hmm,where to set the evaluation time btw?i can't find it in the properties @amodg

Comment: i already found the evaluation time, but the text field cannot be shown in the detail part of my report?

Comment: Hi, I suppose, it will come in the summary part as the expression will evaluated at the end of the report.

Comment: still nothing shown..hmm,is there any other way to do this validation?hmm i can only show the static text when it's located in the header part which will always be generated even though the select query results in null

Comment: Ok, did you try to print the value of REPORT_COUNT? The other way would be to check the no of records in the code and to pass it as a parameter. We can then check something like new Boolean($V{onOfRecords}.intValue()==0. But, this is not recommended. REPORT_COUNT worked perfectly for me...

Comment: the report count worked perfectly too..except when my detail is null, but that's where i wanna put the static error text.. right now i'm putting it in the header, which works just fine using report_count as it's validation..thanks for your big help!i'll figure something out later maybe for putting it in the detail part..